# Swift generic type property and method

Tags: ios, swift, generics, types, controller

How do I store generic type in property and then use that type property to pass in method?

I have factory whose method receives view controllers type but returns instance of that view controller (container takes care of that).

```
public protocol ViewControllerFactoryProtocol {
    func getViewController<T: UIViewController>(type: T.Type) -> UIViewController
}

public class ViewControllerFactory: ViewControllerFactoryProtocol {

private let container: Container

public init(container: Container) {
    self.container = container
}

public func getViewController<T: UIViewController>(type: T.Type) -> UIViewController {
    return self.container.resolve(type)!
}
```

}

And I have property like this

```
var destinationViewController: UIViewController.Type { get }
```

Now I would like to do something like:

```
factory.getViewController(self.destinationViewController)
```

where I declare `destinationViewController` as `LoginViewController.self`

But its not working like that. Weird thing is that it is working if I do it directly:

```
factory.getViewController(LoginViewController.self)
```

Any help?? Thanks

Comment: _"But its not working like that"_ : How does it work then?  Or what's the error message?

Comment: It just throws bad access error.

Comment: Did you check if `self.container.resolve(type)` in `getViewController` returns `nil`?

Comment: Yes, it returns nil...

Comment: That's why it crashes.  You are trying to force-unwrap a nil value.  Debug why does it return nil, then.  Apparently it should return some object instead.

Comment: Thats swinject container so I can't do much of debugging. But weird thing is that factory.getViewController(LoginViewController.self) is working so there must be something with my storage of type to property.

Comment: How do you register types with that container?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without seeing the code for `resolve` it's not possible to say why it's crashing, but I have a good idea. I suspect you're mistaking the difference between generic type parameters and runtime type parameters. Consider this simplified code.

```
func printType<T>(type: T.Type) {
    print("T is \(T.self)")
    print("type is \(type)")
}

class Super {}
class Sub: Super {}

printType(Super.self) // Super/Super. Good.
printType(Sub.self)   // Sub/Sub. Good.

let type: Super.Type = Sub.self
printType(type) // Super/Sub !!!!!!
```

Why is the last case Super/Sub? Because `printType<T>` is resolved at compile time. It looks just at the definitions:

```
func printType<T>(type: T.Type)
let type: Super.Type

printType(type)
```

To make this work, I need a `T` such that `T.Type` is the same as `Super.Type`. Well, that's `Super`. So this gets compiled as:

```
printType<Super>(type)
```

Now at runtime, we see that `type` is equal to `Sub.self`, which is a subtype of `Super.type`, so that's ok. We pass it along to `printType<Super>` and get the response you're seeing.

So probably internal to `resolve`, you're using `T` somewhere that you wanted to use `type`, and that you're trying to "resolve" `UIViewController`, which probably returns nil.

Comment: Can I somehow get exact type I need before calling self.container.resolve(type)? And then pass that and not "type" to resolve method

Comment: I'm not sure if it helps but here is swinjects resolve method inside container: https://github.com/Swinject/Swinject/blob/master/Swinject/Container.swift

Comment: You are passing the type. Swinject doesn't use it. Look around line 133. The run-time value of `serviceType` isn't used. Only the compile-time type is used. This would have to be changed on the framework side. It may not be possible to do this in Swift in a way that matches what Swinject wants to achieve. This framework seems very complicated, and I personally wouldn't recommend it (it swizzles UIStoryboard, which is always a bad sign for stability). But if you do want to use it, you definitely will need to educate yourself on precisely what it's doing.

Comment: Just to reiterate before the next obvious question: I have no idea if there is any small change to Swinject will make this work. I would open an issue with the project.