# Cannot assign value of generic type

Tags: ios, swift, generics

I have generic class - `Class1`.

```
class Class1<T> {
}
```

And I have `Class2` with variable `object1` of type `Class1` and generic type `UIView`

```
class Class2 {
    var object1: Class1<UIView>?
}
```

When I create instance of `Class2` and try to assign to `object1` instance of type `Class1` and generic type `UITableView` I got an error: "Cannot assign value of type `Class1<UITableView>` to type `Class1<UIView>`"

```
var c = Class2()
c.object1 = Class1<UITableView>()
```

However the same logic works for Array. Why?

[image]

Comment: I think there' some compiler magic taking place for `Array` type.  Technically, `Generic<Supertype>` is different type from `Generic<Subtype>` and you can not assign values of the latter to the properties of the former.  But in case of the array, as you can see it does work.

Comment: [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34723935/5501940) might be useful of what are you trying to find...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let me elaborate on Anton’s comment. The question is when you can use a B for an A. Usually you can do that when B is a subtype of A. For instance, you can assign a `UITableView` to a variable of type `UIView`.

So when is something a subtype of something else?

For classes, this is straightforward: if you subclass `B` from `A`, `B` is a subtype of `A`.

For function types, you need to consider the argument types and the return type. A function type `F2` is a subtype of function type `F1` if `F2`’s parameter types are supertypes of `F1`’s parameter and `F2`’s return type is a subtype of `F1`’s return type. You could say that a function must not require more (i.e. it must not require subtypes as parameters but can require supertypes) and must not provide less (i.e. it must not return a supertype but can return a subtype) for its type to be a subtype. The terminology is that the parameter types must be *contravariant* and the return type must be *covariant*.

Example:

```
var f1: UIControl -> UIControl = ...

let f2: UIView -> UIControl = ...
let f3: UIControl -> UIButton = ...
let f4: UIView -> UIButton = ...
f1 = f2  // Fine, f2 takes UIView so it also takes UIControl
f1 = f3  // Fine, f3 returns UIButton which is a UIControl
f1 = f4  // Fine, both of the above

let f5: UIButton -> UIControl
let f6: UIControl -> UIView
let f7: UIButton -> UIView
f1 = f5  // Error, couldn’t call with a UIControl because f5 demands at least a UIButton
f1 = f6  // Error, call would return only a UIView
f1 = f7  // Error, both of the above
```

So the types of `f2`, `f3`, and `f4` are subtypes of `f1`’s type and the types of `f5`, `f6`, and `f7` are not.

Now what about generic types? In Swift, custom types with type parameters are all *invariant*. That is, in your example no `Class1<T2>` object can be used as a `Class1<T1>` object, no matter the relation between `T1` and `T2` (except when `T1` and `T2` are the same type).

However, Swift has indeed some built-in variance rules that makes your example with arrays work: `[UITableView]` (`Array<UITableView>`) is a subtype of `[UIView]` (`Array<UIView>`). Note that the same is true for optionals, i.e. `UITableView?` (`Optional<UITableView>`) is a subtype of `UIView?` (`Optional<UIView>`). So both arrays and optionals are covariant with their type parameter.

Further reading:

- [Liskov Substitution Principle on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle)
- [Mike Ash on Covariance and Contravariance](https://www.mikeash.com/pyblog/friday-qa-2015-11-20-covariance-and-contravariance.html)